# Cant scroll past image on mobile

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

Originally, the images in my theme had imagezoom on hover. However, this made it impossible to scroll over images when viewing the page on mobile phone - you just ended up zooming instead. Because of that, I decided to hide the imagezoom container from images.

However, I still can't scroll when hitting the main image of a product in mobile view. Can someone please help me figure out why?

Example: http://tiny.cc/79r92x
Video of the scroll problem: https://youtu.be/wzWshmPIhiE

I have spoken to my theme developer, but they don't acknowledge the problem.

Comment: Did my answer work out for you in the end?

Comment: Yes and thank you very much for your efforts. I have just accepted your answer :-)

Comment: Cheers. My pleasure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 1606 of your example page you can see the following javascript:

```
jQuery("#sns_product_img_media #zoom_img_media").on("click", function(e) { 
                    var ez = jQuery('#sns_product_img_media #zoom_img_media').data('elevateZoom');  
                    jQuery.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList()); 
                    return false;
                });
```

Remove the line that says `return false;`. That one causes the issue.

You can also test it in your browser console by pasting the following:

```
jQuery("#sns_product_img_media #zoom_img_media").unbind();
jQuery("#sns_product_img_media #zoom_img_media").on("click", function(e) { 
                    var ez = jQuery('#sns_product_img_media #zoom_img_media').data('elevateZoom');  
                    jQuery.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList()); 
                });
```

You'll see that it works well without the return false; statement when testing in mobile view.

(Just to clarify, the issue has to do with the way fancybox is initiated in the theme. )

EDIT:

It turns out the elevatezoom jQuery plugin is the culprit. In the file `http://www.propagandashop.dk/js/sns/elevatezoom/jquery.elevatezoom.js` you should search for the string `touchmove`.

It's defined 3 times, remove the `e.preventDefault()` that's defined in the callback function for the touchmove event.

[image]

After this you should be good!

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help!
I see that your suggestion about pasting the code in console works very well. BUT, it doesn't change anything when I remove the return false from my code. Can you please check the example page again and tell me if you see any other errors? Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm.. I keep having trouble with this. I tried removing the whole jQuery code as well, but that doesnt work either. Maybe it's actually the unbinding part of the console code that solves the issue? Could that be the case? :-)

Comment: Yeah that could be the case indeed. You might want to check out http://www.propagandashop.dk/skin/frontend/sns_avaz/default/js/app.js, and especially the `pointerTarget.on('touchend', function(e) {` line

Comment: It seems it uses different detection methods, and uses e.preventDefault(), which prevents the click event to bubble up and possibly prevents a drag that way

Comment: Hmm. Thanks! Do you think I can safely remove the whole mentioned function from app.js, or should I remove something specific? :-)

Comment: Actually now that I look at the code again, it turns out another part of the script is the culprit. I'll update my answer now

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question once again, but i'm not sure which one is the callback function.. Would that be the first, second or third time the touchmove is defined in the file? Or should I simply remove all three? :-)

Comment: Added a screenshot to the answer!